# CPU USAGE MORE THAN 100% red5sip

Tags: sip, asterisk, red5, openmeetings

I am using SIP Transport with Openmeetings to enable web conferencing through mobile device. But on the server the CPU usage crosses 100% with each SIP transport that is created for a new room. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to control the CPU usage? Already got one laptop's CPU fried because of this.

Answer (score 0):

That situation is not normal. Check your transcoder lib(whatever you use) and try recompile red5sip.

Comment: I tried recompile with new checkout.. & sip video off too..but after adding sip transport into more than 2 rooms..cpu usage cross more than 150%..